# Spring MVC. Выводится только часть форм HTML

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

Можете кто-нибудь посоветовать решение, у меня есть Spring MVC приложение, соединенное с БД PostgreSQL. Возникла проблема, что Spring выводит только часть HTML, когда должен выводить полностью. Далее на фото будет понятнее.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас, здесь представлена только одна форма, когда их должно быть 5.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New coffeeMachine</title>
</head>
<body>

<form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/coffeeMashine}" th:object="${coffeeMachine}">
    <label for="name">Enter name of the drink: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{nameOfTheDrink}" id="name"/>
    <div style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{nameOfTheDrink}">Name Error</div>
    <br/>
    <label for="sort">Enter sort of coffee: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{sortOfCoffee}" id="sort"/>
    <div style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('sort')}" th:errors="*{sortOfCoffee}">Sort Error</div>
    <br/>
    <label for="milk">Enter kind of milk: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{kindOfMilk}" id="milk"/>
    <div style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('milk')}" th:errors="*{kindOfMilk}">Milk Error</div>
    <br/>
    <label for="amount1">Enter amount of drink: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{amountOfDrink}" id="amount1"/>
    <div style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('amount1')}" th:errors="*{amountOfDrink}">Amount of drink Error</div>
    <br/>
    <label for="amout2">Enter amount of coffee: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{amountOfCoffee}" id="amout2"/>
    <div style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('amount1')}" th:errors="*{amountOfCoffee}">Amount of coffee Error</div>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Create!"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>


</body>
</html>
```

Контроллер:

```
@GetMapping("/new")
    public String newPerson(@ModelAttribute("coffeeMachine") CoffeeMachine coffeeMachine) {
        return "coffeeMachine/new";
    }

    @PostMapping()
    public String create(@ModelAttribute("coffeeMachine") @Valid CoffeeMachine coffeeMachine,
                         BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
            return "coffeeMachine/new";

        coffeeMachineDAO.save(coffeeMachine);
        return "redirect:/coffeeMachine";
    }
```

И DAO:

```
public void save(CoffeeMachine coffeeMachine){
        try{
            PreparedStatement statement =
                    connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO coffeeMachine3 VALUES(1, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

            statement.setString(1, coffeeMachine.getNameOfTheDrink());
            statement.setString(2, coffeeMachine.getSortOfCoffee());
            statement.setString(3, coffeeMachine.getKindOfMilk());
            statement.setDouble(4, coffeeMachine.getAmountOfDrink());
            statement.setInt(5, coffeeMachine.getAmountOfCoffee());

            statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Может кто-нибудь знает, как это можно решить?

Comment: Добрый день, ошибок в логе нет при открытии страницы?

Comment: Страница не вывелась полностью скорее всего потому что произошла ошибка на ее отрисовке и было бы полезно увидеть на каком именно месте оборвалась верстка

Comment: Также если была ошибка то должно бы было быть и сообщение об ошибке, которое тоже было бы здорово увидеть

Comment: у вас в методе newPerson в параметрах атрибут модели?..

Comment: А можно модель приложить?